# Clear button for md-select arrow overflow

Tags: html, css, angular-material, md-select

I have a `md-select` inside `md-grid-list` which is part of `md-card` content that looks like this:

```
<md-grid-tile>
     <md-select id="typ" [(ngModel)]="doc.docType" placeholder="Typ Dokumentu">
         <md-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{ state}}</md-option>
     </md-select>

     <button class="clear" [hidden]="!doc.docType" (click)="clear('docType')">X</button>

</md-grid-tile>
```

[image]

As you can read, 'X' buttor renders when there is value selected and clears it on click event. Just sets `md-select` model property to `undefined`

Now, I would like to position 'X' button over the `mat-select-arrow` to hide/cover it.

Can you help me to css style the 'clear' button to move a bit left and hide that arrow? 
When setting `margin-right` it only moves the whole `md-select` left but does not cover the arrow.

I believe this can be helpful to many.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic example for `css` `positioning` if you need to shift `x` to right side you have to play with `position` just like a following example.

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.cross {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px; /* You can play with this property */
  right: 5px; /* You can play with this property */
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span class="cross">x</span>
</div>
```